# /usr/bin/file from Ubuntu 32-bit ARM

Tags: binary

I want "file" binary which is usually located at /usr/bin/ . I want it from 32-bit ARM. I got only 64-bit ubuntu installed on my computer. Can someone please upload me that binary?

thanks in advance

Comment: You have a 64-bit system and you need a 32-bit binary, is that what you are looking for? But why do you need that?

Comment: "file" binary from 64-bit ubuntu won't work on android. I want to use it on android. That's why.

Comment: and you can not download it from the packages directory why? see http://packages.ubuntu.com/

Comment: oh, thank you sir. I didn't know it is available there. sorry. my bad.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/bin/file
file: /usr/bin/file
```

So the package which provides the `/usr/bin/file` executable file is `file`.Install `file` by running,

```
sudo apt-get install file
```

Comment: This won't recreate the binary since apt thinks this package is already installed and would leave the system as it is.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have accidentaly deleted the `/usr/bin/file` binary. You could actually reinstall `file` using

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall file
```

though this would download the entire package rather than the binary itself, this is the cleanest easiest way to get back the binary.

Comment: sorry. I have edited my request, sir.